# Verilog program help 2x4 decoder

Tags: verilog, computer-science

I am very new to verilog and am trying to code this diagram using an an array.

2x4 Diagram

[image: 2x4 Diagram]

So far I have this, but I don't get the output I'm looking for.

```
   module DecoderMod(s, o); // module definition
   input [0:1] s;
   output [0:1] o;
   wire [0:1] snot;


   not(snot[1], s1);
   not(snot[0], s0);

   and(o[0], snot[1], snot[0]);
   and(o[1], snot[1], s[0]);
   and(o[2], s[1]   , snot[0]);
   and(o[3], s[1]   , s[0]);

endmodule

module TestMod;
   reg [0:1] s;
   wire [0:3] o;

   DecoderMod my_decoder(s, o); // create instance

   initial begin
      $monitor("%0d\t%b\t%b", $time, s, o);
      $display("Time  s  o");
      $display("--------------");
   end

   initial begin
      s[1] = 0; s[0] = 0;#1;
      s[1] = 0; s[0] = 1;#1;
      s[1] = 1; s[0] = 0;#1;
      s[1] = 1; s[0] = 1;
   end
endmodule
```

I get this:

```
Time    s       o
--------------------
0       00      x000
1       01      xx00
2       10      x0x0
3       11      xxx1
```

But I want this:

```
Time    s   o
--------------------
0       00  1000
1       01  0100
2       10  0010
3       11  0001
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `s0` and `s1` in your `not` instances, they should be:

```
 not(snot[1], s[1]);
 not(snot[0], s[0]);
```

Comment: You might consider adding `default_nettype none` to the top of your file in the future. The compiler will then warn about wires that haven't been explicitly defined.